# .NET Core Razor Pages Data Binding with partial views on form submission

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've got a an object with an `Address` object as a property which is used several places in my application.  I made a partial view which looks like

```cs
@model Address
<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.AddressLine1"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.AddressLine1" />
    </div>
    ....
```

I use the form like

```cs
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="@Model.Request.Business.Owners[0].FirstName" />
        <input asp-for="@Model.Request.Business.Owners[0].LastName" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

the data renders fine on the entire form, including the partial Address view.  when I submit the form, everyone I reference the Address partial  I get back as null when I submit the form, while the other data is data bound correctly.  Is it possible to bind data to a partial view and have it submit with a form post correctly?

Comment: How are you binding the model? What's your Address object? Could you also show the controller code and the HTML that the partial generates?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Likely, you're not providing context to the partial, so that it can generate the names properly. As-is, the partial is going to want to generate names like `AddressLine1`, when what you actually need for proper binding is `Request.Business.Owners[0].Address.AddressLine1`. I'm assuming you're doing something like:

```
<partial name="_Address" model="Request.Business.Owners[0].Address" />
```

Instead, you need to use the `for` attribute:

```
 <partial name="_Address" for="Request.Business.Owners[0].Address" />
```

Comment: That was indeed the problem.